# How to combine different plots in one graph with Matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, function, numpy, matplotlib

So I have two functions:

```
Y1= np.sin(X)
Y2= X/np.pi
```

I want to plot them in the same graph using `Matplotlib`. To do so, I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi)

Y1= np.sin(X)
Y2= X/np.pi

plt.plot(X,Y1, color='red')
plt.plot(X,Y2, color='blue')

plt.show()
```

All the sources that I could found seem to indicate that using plt.plot() for the different functions firstly and then running plt.show() later helps to plot every function in the same graph. However, when I run this code I get one plot when I run `plt.plot(X,Y1, color='red')`, I get another plot when I run `plt.plot(X,Y2, color='blue')`. But then nothing happens when I run `plt.show()`.

What can I do to plot both functions in the same graph?

Comment: Looks like you are using jupyter. You should run the three lines at once.

Comment: I am using Spyder, but I did run every line by itself indeed. Thank you for your feedback, this works. If you write this as an answer, then I will mark it as the official answer.